# Rendering Zend_Form errors

Tags: php, zend-framework

say i want to attach errors to my `Zend_Form` i found out the default decorators for forms do not include errors. so i tried adding my own ...

in my Zend_Form class

```
$this->setDecorators(array(
    'FormElements',
    array('Errors', array('placement' => 'PREPEND')),
    'Form'
));
```

but if there are no form errors, i get

> Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects
>   parameter 1 to be string, array given
>   in
>   D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\ZendFramework\library\Zend\View\Abstract.php
>   on line 897

am i doing the right thing? removing the line `array('Errors', array('placement' => 'PREPEND'))` fixes it, but why? if there are errors, it renders correctly without that error

## UPDATE

the error seems to come from ~line 53 of `Zend_Form_Decorator_Errors`

```
$errors = $element->getMessages();
```

for forms i think it shld be

```
$errors = $element->getErrorMessages();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
$this->setDecorators(array(
    'FormElements',
    array('FormErrors', array('placement' => 'PREPEND')),
    'Form'
));
```

Comment: that worked. even without `addPrefixPath()` whats `addPrefixPath()` for actually? and for the 2nd param `$path`, is the path relative to my form class? or what?

Comment: This is native decorator so you can use it as is - without any addPrefixPath calls